# SQL efficiency argument, add a column or solvable by query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

I am a recent college graduate and a new hire for software development. Things have been a little slow lately so I was given a db task. My db skills are limited to pet projects with Rails and Django. So, I was a little surprised with my latest task.

I have been asked by my manager to subclass Person with a 'Parent' table and add a reference to their custodian in the Person table. This is to facilitate going from Parent to Form when the custodian, not the Parent, is the FormContact.

Here is a simplified, mock structure of a sql-db I am working with. I would have drawn the relationship tables if I had access to Visio.

We have a table 'Person' and we have a table 'Form'. There is a table, 'FormContact', that relates a Person to a Form, not all Persons are related to a Form. There is a relationship table for Person to Person relationships (Employer, Parent, etc.)

I've asked, "Why this couldn't be handled by a query?" Response, Inefficient. (Really!?!)

So, I ask, "Why not have a reference to the Form? That would be more efficient since you wouldn't be querying the FormContacts table with the reference from child/custodian." Response, this would essentially make the Parent is a FormContact. (Fair enough.)

I went ahead an wrote a query to get from non-FormContact Parent to Form, and tested on the production server. The response time was instantaneous. *SOME_VALUE* is the Parent's fk ID.

```
SELECT FormID 
FROM FormContact 
WHERE FormContact.ContactID 
    IN (SELECT SourceContactID 
        FROM ContactRelationship
        WHERE (ContactRelationship.RelatedContactID = *SOME_VALUE*) 
            AND (ContactRelationship.Relationship = 'Parent'));
```

---

If I am right, "This is an unnecessary change." What should I do, defend my position or should I concede to the managers request?

If I am wrong. What is my error? Is there a better solution than the manager's?

Comment: What, exactly, are you asking? What aspect of the system do you object to?

Comment: I don't understand how a SQL query is inefficient. Especially one as simple as this. Also, I don't see how creating subclass and a column, that would lead to another SQL query is more efficient. The only difference between the two queries is one uses a sub-query and the other has a fk id.

Comment: your query works for a given SOME_VALUE, write a query to work on all rows from FormContact, like a report would do.

Comment: Can you post your managers proposed Query/solution?  I would probably suggest a join instead of the inner select statement.

Comment: Here's just a little advice on being a new hire fresh out of college.  While your solution very well could be better, be careful about how you approach your manager.  I've found that there are some managers who are quite egotistical (for some reason, that's prevalent in this field), and if you slap it in his face that you're idea is better, even if it is, he may not appreciate it.  Just be careful how you approach it.

Comment: Can you post the current table DDL and the proposed table DDL?

Comment: @theTurk: What problem are you saying can be solved with a query instead of adding to the schema? In addition, Andrew is correct in that `join`s would be preferable to your nested subqueries.

Comment: @KM: I'll have to look into that, thanks for the help.
@Andrew: As far as I know, his comment was a blanket statement. I haven't seen a proposed a query, if one exists.
@Aaron: There's my conundrum, it could look bad on me even if I am right.

Comment: @Adam: I want to get from a Non-Contact to a Form. Forms are only related to Contacts. Non-Contacts are related to Contacts. So, I can query the Relationship between a Non-Contact and a Contact, then I can query the Form from the Contact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first, your query could use some reworking. Rather than subselects, try using a `join`:

```
SELECT FormID

FROM FormContact fc

JOIN ContactRelationship cr on cr.SourceContactID = fc.ContactID 
                               and cr.Relationship = 'Parent'

WHERE cr.RelatedContactID = @parent_id
```

Secondly, the issue you're dealing with is normalization vs. performance. From a purity perspective, yes, your solution is "more correct" (as you aren't duplicating data, which eliminates the possibility for the disparities in the duplicated data causing conflicts and aberrant behavior), but pure normalization is not always the wisest course of action.

Normalization can induce performance penalties, especially in larger data sets. These penalties have to be weighed alongside the benefits from normalization to see which side "wins".

That being said, I can't see how joining the `Person` table again on the `ParentID` column (I'm assuming that's what you'd be adding) would provide a performance boost over the join listed above, assuming that the columns in question are properly indexed.

If the query above works for you and you do rigorous performance testing to show that it's valid, take it to your manager and ask for his input. Because you're new and fresh out of college, be very willing to defer to your manager's judgment and wishes on this one. There will be much bigger battles to fight in the future.

Comment: I like this answer. I can adapt the SQL Query to the actual db and the explanation of normalization v. performance is informative. Also, it addresses the manager issue. Thanks.